# spi does not start on orange pi 3 lts with armbian

Tags: spi, armbian

there is a need to use the spi interface on orange pi 3 lts with armbian OS.

I do everything according to the instructions, put wiringOP, go to armbian-config, turn on spi-spidev1 and for some reason CE.1 pin is in the OFF state, not ALT2 like all other spi pins. Please help, I changed the system several times, tried different versions, so far without success
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Dzv.png)